# mod_authz_core.c Logging

Tags: debian, logging, apache-2.4

So I'm pretty new to the whole server admin world and just got a fresh install of a server up and running. While looking at my apache2 logs, I've seen a lot of mod_authz_core.c lines. Another guy I work with says that I've some debug setting turned on. Doing a lot of research, I was told to change the Loglevel in the apache2.conf. I tried the following values: 
error ssl:warn
error
notice

It was originally on warn. After each time, I did a graceful restart and it's still logging all of these. Is there something else I'm missing? I've seen options to just stop logging services all together. I'm thinking that's not wise. :)

Any tips of the trade will be appreciated to this newbie! I am on a debian server if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If people didn't see my response to cherdt, it turns out that some syntax has changed from apache 2.2 (where the site previously lived) to 2.4. Viewing the conf file for the one site and according to http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html, this may cause a authz_core warning but it's okay (according to another thread). I also had a LogLevel in the conf file which was set to debug. Changed it to warn and reloaded the server. Everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if the LogLevel is set elsewhere in the config files, there may be another LogLevel directive that is overriding apache2.conf.

You can check by running

```
grep -R LogLevel /etc/apache2/*.conf
```

Comment: Finally figured it out after digging everywhere. Google was not really helping me that much. That command above pulled nothing in the apache2 folder. Turns out it was in the conf file for one of the sites enabled. I copied the conf file from an apache 2.2 server and some things changed. Thanks for your input though!!